# Display name of private Organic Group

Tags: organic-groups

I have a content type that is group content. There is a second field, "Other Groups Involved with Delivery," which is an entity reference for the Group content type. On the edit page, I can select "Core" which is a private group. But when the node is displayed, the field is missing. Devel shows it being loaded, but it is missing by the time to render it.

I do want the content in the group protected, but I don't want to deny the existence of the group.

What do I need to change?